# If $G$ be the centroid of...

Tags: analytic-geometry

If $G$ be the centroid of $\triangle ABC$, prove that $AB^{2} + BC^{2} + CA^{2} = 3(GA^{2}+GB^{2}+GC^{2}).$

Please help me. I couldn't get even to the first step. However,  i guess centroid is the point of intersection of medians of triangle and median is the the line that joins the vertex to the mid point of opposition side, not the perpendicular. Am I right?

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$1)$ If $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ then $GA=(2/3)AM$.

$2)$ Use Stewart's theorem to find $AM$:
[image]

$$AB^2\cdot CM+AC^2\cdot BM=BC(AM^2+BM\cdot CM)\quad (1)$$

Use that $$BM=CM=BC/2$$

and then $(1)$ becomes:

$$ AM^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(2AB^2+2AC^2-BC^2\right)$$

So,

$$GA^2=\frac{1}{9}\left(2AB^2+2AC^2-BC^2\right)$$

Use the same idea to find $GB^2$ and $GC^2$.

Can you finish?

Comment: What is Stewart theorem?

Comment: see here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart's_theorem

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more?  I can't get all.

Comment: Ok, I will write in more details.

Comment: Is that the Stewart theorem you have used?

Comment: Yes, it is! Just check with the link

Comment: But I am not being to use that for other two sides. Could you please show me only the application of Stewart theorem in this question where other it is to be used?

Comment: @NeWtoN: better now?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.